# Add parameter to admin file for pkgrm

Tags: package-management, solaris, uninstall

I'm trying to do a pkgadd on Solaris with non-interactive. Somehow `pkgadd -d /home/mypackage -n` doesn't work. While reading the man page, I found out that i can disable interaction by using admin file. So i followed the guideline [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5174/admin-4.html#scrolltoc). When i tried to run 
`pkgadd -d /home/mypackage -a /home/admin` it still prompt for user input.

*I create the admin file at /home/

This is the display:

```
The following packages are available:
 1  mypackage    mypackage
                 (all) 4.4.0

Select package (s) you wish to process (or 'all' to process all packages). (default: all) [?,??,q]:
```

Google then lead me to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/149482/nocheck-within-admin-file-for-pkgadd-still-asks-questions) site. By improving a bit, I manage to make it run with the command `pkgadd -d /home/mypackage -a /home/admin 'all'`

Since pkgadd can be done, I assume pkgrm should be the same as well. So I tried `pkgrm -a /home/admin mypackage`.

Then a prompt appear.

```
The following package is currently installed:
   mypackage   mypackage
               (all) 4.4.0

Do you want to remove this package? [y,n,?,q]
```

Then I thought maybe its just the same problem as pkgadd. So I tried `pkgrm -a /home/admin 'y' mypackage`. Instead it gave me an error.

```
pkgrm: ERROR: no package associated with <y>
```

What is it exactly that I should pass so that I can do pkgrm non-interactively. Should i add another parameter inside the admin file? If so, what is the parameter? This is the parameter that I have tried using:

```
remove=nocheck
removal=nocheck
confirm=nocheck
```

All these tries cause a `WARNING: unknown admin parameter`

This is the admin file that I use:

```
 mail=
 instance=nocheck
 partial=nocheck
 runlevel=nocheck
 idepend=nocheck
 space=nocheck
 setuid=nocheck
 conflict=nocheck
 authentication=nocheck
 action=nocheck
 rscriptalt=root
 bsedir=default
```

I am using Solaris 10 i386

Comment: Try `echo y | pkgrm …` or `yes | pkgrm …`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a hint [here](https://peterpap.net/index.php/Removing_Solaris_Packages_Non-Interactively). I tried to apply the command with `-n` and it works!!
The command should finally be `pkgrm -n -a /export/home/admin mypackage`

Answer (score 1):

For removing a package without asking for dependency, if you are okay, you can include

```
rdepend=nocheck
```

in the admin file.